Formula that can add X number of rows (based on the value in another cell)
Hoping you can help - I have a formula that will build table rows (here).
But I have data that is slightly different and hoping there's a way to adjust the formula to make it work.
Option 1.
I basically have an asset column and a quantity column, where there the quantity > 1 I need the Asset to show in that many rows. E.g. Asset with Quantity x 5 should have 5 rows.
Option 2.
I think I can make the top linked formula work if I can reformat my assets in an additional column so the text in column A (assets) is multiplied by the Quantity (column b), so should appear in column C as 'Asset, Asset, Asset' (if the quantity is x3).


This question is off-topic for [su] and I will transfer this to an answer if it gets migrated to [webapps.se] =TOCOL(INDEX(SPLIT(REPT(A3:A&"!",1/(1/B3:B)),"!")),3) or if the volume exceeds text string limits then =TOCOL(MAP(A3:A,B3:B,LAMBDA(t,n,INDEX(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,n)/0,t)))),1)
